# What are  the correct arguments for overlayarea?

Tags: tables, beamer, overlays

When I compile the following code, pdflatex takes up 100% of one of my CPU and doesn't stop. I'm probably passing wrong arguments to overlayarea, since I have no idea what they should do (the Beamer_Guide doesn't mention them)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
            \begin{tabular}{c}
                    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{0cm}
                            \only<1>{hi}
                            \only<2>{there}
                    \end{overlayarea}
            \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

So, why does this clog my CPU and what are the two arguments in overlayarea supposed to do?

Comment: The Beamer User Guide sure mentions the two arguments (on Section 9.5 Dynamically Changing Text or Image): `\begin{overlayarea}{⟨area width⟩}{⟨area height⟩} ⟨environment contents⟩ \end{overlayarea}`

Comment: Freaky!  Taking out the tabular *or* the overlayarea stops the hike in CPU.  (Confirmed also with xelatex so it isn't an issue with the engine, also confirmed with `1cm` for each length argument.)

Comment: Nesting the `tabular` inside the `overlayarea` also works.

Comment: turns out I had the wrong Beamer Guide! Thanks Gonzalo. I have to try nesting the other way around, as you suggest, especially in my "real life" example which is quite more complicated than this

Answer (score 12):

The Beamer User Guide sure mentions the two arguments (on Section 9.5 *Dynamically Changing Text or Image*):

```
\begin{overlayarea}{⟨area width⟩}{⟨area height⟩} 
⟨environment contents⟩ 
\end{overlayarea}
```

For the problem mentioned, nest the `tabular` inside the `overlayarea`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{1cm}
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    \only<1>{hi}
    \only<2>{there}
  \end{tabular}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So the ``area height`` is ``1cm``? I don't understand, surely the height is greater than that? The beamer guide example has ``3cm``. My slide compiles great, but its height is more like 8cm. What is it about the meaning of ``area height`` that I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: It's the size of the overlay area, not of the slide.

Answer (score 2):

Another environment in the `beamer` documentation, which is likely more user-friendly than the `overlayarea` environment, is the `overprint` environment listed under section 9.5 "*Dynamically Changing Text or Images*" (page 84). Based on my usage of it, my understanding is that it dynamically adjusts the height and width of the overlay area to minimize positional jumps between consecutive images (note that the `area width` parameter is **optional**):

> ```
> \begin{overprint}[⟨area width⟩]
> ⟨environment contents⟩
> \end{overprint}
> ```
>
> The `⟨area width⟩` defaults to the text width. Inside the environment, use `\onslide` commands to specify different things that should be shown for this environment on different slides. The `\onslide` commands are used like `\item` commands. Everything within the environment will be placed in a rectangular area
> of the specified width. The height and depth of the area are chosen large enough to accommodate the largest contents of the area. The overlay specifications of the `\onslide` commands must be disjoint. This may be a problem for handouts, since, there, all overlay specifications default to 1. If you use the option handout, you can disable all but one `\onslide` by setting the others to 0.
>
> *Example*:
>
> ```
> \begin{overprint}
> \onslide<1| handout:1>
> Some text for the first slide.\\
> Possibly several lines long.
> \onslide<2| handout:0>
> Replacement on the second slide. Suppressed for handout.
> \end{overprint}
> ```